# How do I do databinding in XAML?

Tags: xaml, data-binding

I want to define the 3D object in XAML by binding them. All the 3D points data is available in a file having XML format.

The sample points are as follows:

```
 <Points>
  <point x="81.955430" y="-0.936101" z="0.932556" />
  <point x="81.950562" y="-0.924299" z="0.903429" />
  <point x="81.949074" y="-0.921351" z="0.896044" />
  <point x="81.943974" y="-0.912902" z="0.874677" />
...
```

There are approximately 1000 points.

How can I import them in `MeshGeometry3D`, by binding in XAML?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you want to do? What do you mean by “define in XAML”? Could for example show some sample of how you would imagine this could work (even if the code doesn't work)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx). Here's an [example of how to use XmlDataProvider](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/04/binding-to-xml/).